# What element saved Iron Man from his blood poisoning?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2008, iron-man-2

I just watched *Iron Man 1&2* the other day. I'm new to the entire story.

In IM2 we learn that his blood is being poisoned and that he has tried every combination of every existing element as a cure - unsuccessfully. Then he deducts "the key" from the Expo park's plans which saves him.

What is that key? What element had he not tried?

*I realize that the movie story has to be simplified, compared to the original story, so there are probably story elements that I have completely missed because they're only in the original works. We also saw that in LOTR.*

Comment: Clearly it's [Unobtanium](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Unobtainium).

Comment: My guess is that it's whatever the element the Tesseract (Space stone) is made of. Tony sees a sketch of it in his father's notebook and skims past it, but then at the beginning of `Avengers`, he immediately takes notice of it in the briefing packet that Agent Coulson brings, and probably puts 2+2 together at that point.

Answer (score 18):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium#Film) says that:

> Although unnamed in the film itself, the **movie's novelization identifies the element as vibranium**, so named by Stark because it shares characteristics with uranium and has similar transgenic properties to another fictional element named "vibernum".

From [*Iron Man 2: A Novel*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/7679127-iron-man-2)

> The moment of truth was nearly at hand in the transition of the grand vibranium experiment from creation of a single molecule to production of usable quantities of said molecule. Tony stood with a pair of tongs, the pincer end of which extended into a mean high-energy electromagnetic blast furnace where, with any luck, a whole lot of vibranium was precipitating into a kettle that the pincer would shortly grasp and remove.

Comment: I didn't think that Iron Man would be in the Wikipedia but now that you mention it, why shouldn't he be? Thank you! Also, it figures that the magic element is a fictional one. Hadn't thought of that either!

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. Vibranium was a well-known element at that point - Captain America's shield is made out of it, and that shield was made by Tony Stark's father. He should have known to try it sooner!

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller The problem is that there was no way to synthesize vibranium. Howard Stark himself says in the Captain America movie that the shield was made of the only vibranium in the world, implying that they couldn't synthesize more.

Comment: @Steam He said it was the only vibranium they had. In context, "they" most likely meant "our side," since there's plenty of Vibranium in the country of Wakanda.

Comment: @hairboat You're correct, Wikipedia was wrong here and has since removed that section. See my answer for the correct name of the element.

Comment: This answer should be taken down as it is currently incorrect. The other answer should be selected as correct.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in a quote from the novel. Originally Tony isn't quite sure what he's made, but after studying it for a while, he seems a lot more certain that it's vibranium or some sort of molecule largely comprising semi-pure vibranium

Answer (score 8):

## Badassium

This can be seen in *Marvel's The Avengers Prelude: Fury's Big Week* Volume 8:

[image: Marvel's The Avengers Prelude: Fury's Big Week_ Volume 8 panel, Fury, Clint and someone else talk; relevant section quoted below]

> **Fury:** He's working on a patent for "Badassium," but has encountered several bureaucratic obstacles.