# what is the atomic number of URU element found in Asgard?

Tags: marvel, mjolnir

Thor's hammer is made up of URU element which is found only in Asgard. What is the atomic number of URU?

Comment: Its a fictional metal. Only non fictional metals find their place in periodic table.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a real-life explanation for a fictional subject.

Comment: Lets be fair. This may be a silly question, but is it a BAD question? We ask for real-life explanations for all sorts of sci-fi and fantasy concepts.

Comment: @Flimzy, one of the close reasons is for asking for real-life explanations of sci-fi elements. That said, it is *possible* that [Vibranium](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22997/what-element-saved-iron-man-from-his-blood-poisoning) or may show up in a revised MCU periodic table. If that does, does Uru, as well? My guess is that it's never been addressed.

Comment: Editing the question to focus specifically on a fictional version of the periodic table *may* help keep this from being closed.

Comment: @phantom42: I don't have the rep to VtC yet, so I've never seen that close reason... I think focusing on the fictional periodic table is the only reasonable way to interpret this question.

Comment: Do we even know that it's an element, rather than a magical alloy?

Comment: @evilsoup [Marvel Universe (hosted by Marvel and curated by Marvel employees)](http://marvel.com/universe/Mjolnir) describes it as an "Asgardian metal". [Marvel Wiki (a more public wiki)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Uru) describes it as "a metal ore".

Comment: Uru is native to, and only found in Asgard,and therefore would never appear on a human periodic table of elements anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is currently unknown, as the authors have not provided this answer.  There is no way to logically deduce the answer, aside from one being provided by the creator(s) of the universe in which the element is found.

Comment: Somewhere I have read that Uru has a property of magical enchantments. So I am eager to know that under which group one can list this element in the periodic table?

Comment: @ Flimzy, atoms were postulated by the ancient Greeks. Perhaps the answer will be formulated 'in universe' at some future date. Tony stark may co-author the paper.

Comment: @IhorSypko: It's possible that an in-universe explanation could be devised, but it would not be official in any meaningful way. All modern adaptations of such mythology are essentially high-budget "fan fiction." Such an in-universe explanation would only be valid within the context of that specific adaptation (which this question is not asking about).

Comment: But Uru is specific to the Marvel version of Thor; it doesn't exist in the mythology. So Marvel could come up with an official answer to this question (which is not to say that they have).

Comment: @Micah: That does change the possibility of an answer being created later...