# Is the Arc Reactor made from the same material as the Tesseract?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

Are they, the Arc Reactor and Tesseract, made of the same material?

(I haven't found any concrete theories about this).

Comment: Any particular reason why you think they are?

Comment: @joshbirk - I'm willing to bet it's because they're both bright blue when turned on.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that the active component of the Arc Reactors seen in Iron Man (e.g. ignoring the casing made of steel and glass and the electrical components within) is [Palladium](https://ironman.fandom.com/wiki/Arc_Reactor) and latterly [Vibranium](https://marvel-movies.fandom.com/wiki/Arc_Reactor).

By comparison, the "infinity stone" (AKA the [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Gems)) is one of a set of Gems (or Crystals) comprising the remains of an entity known as '[Nemesis](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/nemesise.htm)'. While the actual *element* of the crystals are not described in-canon, I think we can be pretty sure that it's neither Palladium nor Vibranium since both are **opaque** metals in their crystalline forms.

[image]

What may be causing the confusion is that both artifacts seem to create the same sort of blue energy that seems common in recent Marvel features.

[image: Arc Reactor] [image: Tesseract]

Comment: It wasn't Vibranium but [Badassium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/235794/58193).