# How did S.H.I.E.L.D. get Vibranium?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield, vibranium, shield

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 1, Phil Coulson mentions that the interrogation room on ["The Bus" (S.H.I.E.L.D. 6-1-6)](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Bus) is made of a Vibranium alloy. In addition, Daisy Johnson stays in a safe house, [Retreat](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Retreat) (supposedly built by Bruce Banner) in Season 2 that seems to be made of the same material and configuration as the interrogation room. And finally, [Fury's Toolbox](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Toolbox) is also mentioned to be made of Vibranium (at least on the outside). How did S.H.I.E.L.D. get Vibranium for these things? All the items in question were created prior to the events of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* or *Black Panther*, when Vibranium became more well-known and used for things other than Captain America's shield. **How did S.H.I.E.L.D. get the Vibranium for these things?**

Comment: Tony Stark was able to make some using a particle accelerator. Probably SHIELD has at least the same capability

Comment: He didn't make Vibranium in Iron Man 2, as per the answers (and comments) of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22997/what-element-saved-iron-man-from-his-blood-poisoning)

Comment: The novelisation explicitly confirms that it's Vibranium though.